# How to get the first row from the txt File in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, text-files

This is my code for reading the txtfile and put it in the datagridview

```
Dim filename As String = String.Empty
Dim TextLine As String = ""
Dim SplitLine() As String


    ofd1.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*"
    ofd1.FilterIndex = 2
    ofd1.RestoreDirectory = True
    ofd1.Title = "Open Text File"

    'get the filename of the txt file
    If ofd1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        filename = ofd1.FileName
    End If

    'if the filename is existing
    If System.IO.File.Exists(filename) = True Then

        Dim objReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(filename)

        Do While objReader.Peek() <> -1
            TextLine = objReader.ReadLine()
            SplitLine = Split(TextLine, ",")
            dvList.Rows.Add(SplitLine)
        Loop

    End If
```

This is the txt File:

```
False, 1-305-9097-01-2, 879.75, 122009, fr
False, 1-305-9097-02-2, 879.75, 122009, fr
False, 1-305-9097-02-3, 879.75, 122009, fr
False, 1-305-9097-03-5, 899.75, 122009, fr
```

Now I want to get only the first record of my txtfile and put it in the msgbox, How can I do this?

I tried this:

```
MsgBox(SplitLine.tostring)
```

But the output of this code is this: **System.String[]**

Thank you.

Comment: The first time in your loop, `TextLine` contains the first record already.

Comment: @DarkCthulhu: Thank you sir for pointing that out, I thought I can use splitline, I have already made a working code for this, Thank you again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it without 2 separate readers, since you already have the value available.

```
Dim objReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(filename)
Dim lineCount as Integer 'lines read so far in file

Do While objReader.Peek() <> -1
    TextLine = objReader.ReadLine()
    If lineCount = 0 Then msgbox(TextLine) 'will show msgbox in first iteration
    SplitLine = Split(TextLine, ",")
    dvList.Rows.Add(SplitLine)
    lineCount = lineCount + 1 'increment lineCount
Loop
```

Answer (score 1):

> Dim First as Boolean = True

Edit the loop like this:

```
Do While objReader.Peek() <> -1
    TextLine = objReader.ReadLine()
    If First Then MessageBox(TextLine) : First = False
    SplitLine = Split(TextLine, ",")
    dvList.Rows.Add(SplitLine)
Loop
```

Comment: Ahh I see, This code will also work for me, Thank you for this one.

Comment: dude, do u still use VB6 ? :)

Comment: No sir, I'm ung vb.net, why? is it because of the msgbox? :)

Comment: Ahh, Ok thank you :) I'm a newbie in vb.net, I will use this now

Answer (score 0):

I have already made a working code for this one, here it is:

```
Dim msgboxReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(filename)

  msgbox(msgboxReader.ReadLine())

Dim objReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(filename)

    Do While objReader.Peek() <> -1
        TextLine = objReader.ReadLine()
        SplitLine = Split(TextLine, ",")
        dvList.Rows.Add(SplitLine)
    Loop
```

**UPDATE** 
I just declare another reader to read the first line only

Comment: Once you advance the reader by a line by calling that, the first record won't be parsed within do..while().

Comment: I don't think you understand. `dvList` won't contain the first record if you call ReadLine() once outside the loop.

Comment: @DarkCthulhu: Hi sir, I have updated my question, can you tell me if this is correct?, because in my code, its working now, Thank you for the help.

Comment: That is correct @Matthew. But there is no need for another reader. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code work just fine for me (but maybe, going to be slow with long files).

```
'' fileToOpen is the var with address of file (E.g.: c:\txt.txt)
Dim lineOneFromFile As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines(fileToOpen)(0)
```